# Can every contractible space be embedded as a convex subset of a vector space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, convex-geometry, topological-vector-spaces

Given a contractible topological space $X$, is there (or what are some conditions for the existence of) a continuous embedding $\iota:X\hookrightarrow V$ into some topological vector space $V$ such that $D:=\iota(X)\subseteq V$ is a convex subset? What if $X$ is assumed metrizable?

Comment: Compare your question to the examples and counterexamples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space#Examples_and_counterexamples .

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: I see, looks like the cone over the Hawaiian earring is the culprit. Then, of course, we may extend the question to which conditions are needed for an embedding to exist. Local contractability is one.

Comment: A tripod is a locally contractible counter-example.

Comment: A necessary condition that is not satisfied by the tripod: all points should have a system of neighborhoods with connected boundary.

Comment: Very often absolute retracts which are infinite-dimensional manifolds (or absorbing spaces) admit such an embedding.